# VGG16 different epoch and batch size generating the same result

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to learn how vgg16 works. Below is my code, using vgg16 for another classification.

```
# Generate a model with all layers (with top)
model_vgg16_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
model_vgg16_conv.summary()

# create your own input format
input = Input(shape=(128,128,3),name = 'image_input')

# Use the generated model
output_vgg16_conv = model_vgg16_conv(input)

# Add the fully-connected layers
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(output_vgg16_conv)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

#Create your own model 
model = Model(input=input, output=x)

#In the summary, weights and layers from VGG part will be hidden, but they will be fit during the training
model.summary()

# Specify an optimizer to use
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

# Choose loss function, optimization method, and metrics (which results to display)
model.compile(
    optimizer = adam,
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=10,verbose=2)
# model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=30,batch_size=100,verbose=2)
result = model.predict(y_test) # same result
```

For some reason, using different epoch size and batch size generate exactly the same result. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Exact same result of what?

Comment: model's predict function

Comment: Provide additional information as what's your dataset size both training and test, what' s the score you are getting, how many classes you have etc